# superuser pass switch to shell script

Tags: bash

I need to run a shell script as another user while logged in as root.  Something along the lines of

```
su <user> ./scriptname -d
```

where the -d bit is the switch to be passed to *scriptname*.

However, when I attempt to execute the command as shown above su complains that -d is not a valid option and presents me with a list of valid options.  How do I get it to understand that the -d is meant for consumption by the script not itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`su <user> -c './scriptname -d'`